# Set combo box initially to empty when using datasource

Tags: c, winforms, combobox

I'm populating a combo box with data from a database using the DataSource property.
I need the field of the combo box to be initially empty.
I've tried:

```
cbPerson.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

but this doesn't work.

I've tried the solutions here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/4ea45757-3ded-4dc0-b82d-dcd33ea4c1d9/

There was one that said that you should first set the selected index to 0, and then to -1, but that doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have an empty list item at a certain index, generally first (as with the usual "Please select...", and such kinds of defaults you see). You can use the `Insert` method of `Items`:

```
cbPerson.Items.Insert("", 0);
```

That might work, depending on which technology you're using, which you failed to specify. But whatever project type, the requirement is going to be very similar.

Comment: I guess you meant cbPerson.Items.Insert(0, ""); I've tried that. It doesn't work because I'm using the DataSource property. I can't manually add items.

Comment: You can, just set the `AppendDataBoundItems` to true.

Comment: You still haven't said which tech. you're using though.

Comment: I can't find the property. Sorry, I forgot. I'm developing a windows forms app.

Answer (score 0):

you will probably have(since you use the datasource property),in your load event 2 lines
 first a comment and second the code that populates combobox....comment that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
cbPerson.SelectedIndex = -1;
cbPerson.Datasource= Nothing;
```